# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__ with f-string in Python

Tags: python

I noticed something strange when formatting my variable into a consistent width of 11 characters:

```py
>>> a = 1234
>>> b = None

>>> f'{a}'
'1234'
>>> f'{b}'
'None'

>>> f'{a:>11}'
'       1234'
>>> f'{b:>11}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

Comment: I know that this likely has been asked before, but I was looking to provide a "canonical" question that is not just a wall of code. I've run into this issue multiple times myself and I'm always confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would think that using an f-string would eliminate the need for an explicit call to `str`, but the f-string construction gets re-routed to a call of `b.__format__`.

**You need to ensure `b` is not `None` by calling `str`**:

```
>>> f'{str(b):>11}'
'       None'
```

Comment: `f'{b!s:>11}'` can be used as well (`s` for `__str__`).